# how to get the excel workbook mathematical operators using apache poi 3.6?

Tags: java, apache-poi

In my application, i want to get all the operators that Excel WorkBook supports using apache poi 3.6...

Please guide me to get this issue properly?

Saravanan.P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the functions that are implemented should be found in the *org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions* package:
http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/functions/package-summary.html

FunctionEval holds the registration of all the functions, which may be the best place to see them all as a list:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/eval/FunctionEval.java

Since you mention wanting to know those for just Apache POI 3.6, you'll need to check the source code for that version, not trunk! Either download the source release, or you can [find the source in SVN](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/tags/REL_3_6/)

Alternately, if you're able to upgrade to a newer copy of Apache POI, more recent versions provide a way to query the functions with implementations at runtime!

You can now use the [FunctionEval.getSupportedFunctionNames() method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/eval/FunctionEval.html#getSupportedFunctionNames%28%29) to get a list of the functions which are implemented in your version of Apache POI. To get a list of functions that POI knows the existence of, but has no implementation for, you need the related [FunctionEval.getNotSupportedFunctionNames() method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/eval/FunctionEval.html#getNotSupportedFunctionNames%28%29). Note that the latter won't be exhaustive, as if POI doesn't know the name of a function it won't be able to tell you what it isn't! Finally, for the Analysis ToolPak function, there's a matching set of methods available. Those are [AnalysisToolPak.getSupportedFunctionNames()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/atp/AnalysisToolPak.html#getSupportedFunctionNames%28%29) and [AnalysisToolPak.getNotSupportedFunctionNames()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/atp/AnalysisToolPak.html#getNotSupportedFunctionNames%28%29)