# Apache POI or Excel formula grammar

Tags: excel, apache-poi

Is there somewhere a formal definition of the grammar of the formulas parsed by Apache POI, or by Excel? If there isn't, I would be content with a list of all the operators supported by Apache POI. This question here [how to get the excel workbook mathematical operators using apache poi 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332569/how-to-get-the-excel-workbook-mathematical-operators-using-apache-poi-3-6) contains a list of all the supported functions (which is great, I also need that intel), but what I'm asking is about the operators (you know, +, -, and what else?)... and anything else that can appear in the formula (parenthesis, curly braces, commas, semicolons, etc).

But if anyone can provide a formal definition of the grammar (BNF, maybe), it would be awesome.

Comment: Did you try [Chapter 3 (Formulas) of the OpenOffice guide to the Excel file format](https://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

Your best bet is probably [Chapter 3 (Formulas)](https://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf) of the [OpenOffice guide to the Excel file format](https://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf)

Alternately, you could look at [section 2.2.2 (Formulas) of the Microsoft .xls file format doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd910615%28v=office.12%29.aspx) ([pdf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313154%28v=office.12%29.aspx)), but the Microsoft docs don't seem to be as helpfully laid out for what you're after